# msgpack: pack the class in member-function

Tags: c++, msgpack

I'm pretty new to "msgpack". I'm trying to pack the user-defined class:

```
MyClass::Pack()
{
    msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
    msgpack::pack(sbuf, this);
}
```

But compiler (VC 9.0) says me

```
error C2228: left of '.msgpack_pack' must have class/struct/union third_party\msgpack\include\msgpack\object.hpp 218
```

The only way I've found:

```
MyClass::Pack()
{
    MyClass copy(this);
    msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
    msgpack::pack(sbuf, copy);
}
```

But what if I don't want to make a copy (e.g. it is heavy operation or requires many additional resources)? Can I do this without a copy ctor? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `msgpack::pack(sbuf, this);` could be `msgpack::pack(sbuf, *this);` to get an object (`this` is just a pointer) ... and I'm not sure that `MyClass copy(this);` is calling a proper copy constructor... maybe I'm wrong, I did not use msgpack yet, I just see C++ :(

Comment: Damn, how can I miss this. Thanks, seems to be working solution.